# jquery cycle IE7 transparent png problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm having trouble getting jquery cycle to work when I have transparent png files in IE7

It's fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE (version 7) I get a black colour where
the png transparency is during the fade.

Can this be made to work right?

Answer (score 56):

unfortunately, though IE7 supports transparent PNG's, only one filter can be applied to an element at a time.

What is happening in your application is that IE7 is applying the alpha filter to your PNG, and is then asked by jQuery to apply another alpha filter for the fade. This has visible results like you said.

The way to get around this is to nest your png inside a container and then fade the container. Sort of like this:

```
<div id="fadeMe">
    <img src="transparent.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Another way to get around this is this simple jQuery plugin that i used because i couldn't change the structure. I would give attribution but I honestly cant remember where i found it.

```
/* IE PNG fix multiple filters */
(function ($) {
    if (!$) return;
    $.fn.extend({
        fixPNG: function(sizingMethod, forceBG) {
            if (!($.browser.msie)) return this;
            var emptyimg = "empty.gif"; //Path to empty 1x1px GIF goes here
            sizingMethod = sizingMethod || "scale"; //sizingMethod, defaults to scale (matches image dimensions)
            this.each(function() {
                var isImg = (forceBG) ? false : jQuery.nodeName(this, "img"),
                    imgname = (isImg) ? this.src : this.currentStyle.backgroundImage,
                    src = (isImg) ? imgname : imgname.substring(5,imgname.length-2);
                this.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + src + "', sizingMethod='" + sizingMethod + "')";
                if (isImg) this.src = emptyimg;
                else this.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + emptyimg + ")";
            });
            return this;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**NOTE** Originally the plugin was written to fix PNG transparency in IE6 but I modified it to work with your problem in IE6+.

Sidenote: I cant remember off the top of my head but i think that IE8 may have the same problem. Correct me if i'm wrong :)

Comment: I would give this significantly more than +1, if I could.

Comment: Yes it appears IE8 also has this problem

Comment: have you tried dd_belatedPng (http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/)? It uses VML and should work with the fades (e.g. filter:alpha(opacity=n));

Comment: I can also confirm that this is a problem in IE8, just in case anyone is still having doubts.

Comment: Amazing dude you are awesome.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Unfortunately, that does not work for IE8 unless you force compatibility mode to emulate IE7 which seems a bit backward.

Comment: The first method works in IE8 (and 7?) if the outer container has an opaque background color. Otherwise, no joy. Kind of defeats the purpose of using PNGs with transparency.

Comment: Not sure what my issue was with the jQuery plugin method, but I wrote a plugin based on [an answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204457/how-to-solve-hack-fading-semi-transparent-png-bug-in-ie8/4126528#4126528) and noticed that it's basically the same as this. I probably screwed it up some how before. Here's [my version](https://gist.github.com/1318344).

Answer (score 15):

This has been driving me mad for the last few days! Finally found a decent solution that works pretty well.

Add this to your CSS:

```
img {  
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Credit: [Dan Tello](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=590295#postcount4722567)

Comment: I tested several other fixes and found they made IE slow, with this one it is blazing fast

Comment: This worked great for me on IE8 - I did not test on IE7.  The other solutions in this thread did not work in my case.  Thanks!

Comment: So far the only fix that has worked without fail for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Try adding

`cleartype:  true,
    cleartypeNoBg:  true`

to your cycle jquery arugments.
It should be fine now :)

Comment: For us, that didn't work while the images are acutually transitioning. The black appeared during the fade, then disappeared after.

Comment: This combined with using png8 works for me on IE7, but not on IE8 - as with rjmunro, I get a thin black border during the transitions.

Comment: This saved the day for general HTML slides in JQuery Cycle for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why this isn't the best answer is beyond me. This is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Coupled with the "wrap the image in a div / fade the div" tactic previously mentioned, using this line of CSS will fix the IE issue:

```
#div img {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (src='../images/bubble_intro_ph1.png'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked to just include the filter property with blank value in jQuery's .animate()function

Maybe this will work for you, too.

```
$("#btn").animate({opacity:1,"margin-left":"-25px", filter:''});
```

Comment: this just disables the animation all together, but fixes the image-problem. Fine for me as a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

> Internet Explorer 7 has some issues
>   with fading transparent PNGs. If
>   you've gotten to the this page because
>   you're seeing a black border where the
>   transparent edges in your PNG are,
>   then here are some tips for fixing the
>   problem:
>
> 1. Do not fade the element directly, but fade a parent container
>      holding the PNG. This may mean you
>      need to add a wrapper element to your
>      code.
> 2. Give the parent element a background color.
> 3. Lastly, if you're still having problems, try giving your parent element
>      the old `zoom: 1` trick. Give the
>      parent element a style declaration of
>      `zoom: 1` (either via CSS or an inline
>      style.) This will force IE to give the
>      element `hasLayout`—which tends to fix
>      all sorts of weird display issues in
>      IE.

**Source:** [Fading a 24-bit transparent PNG in IE7+](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/2/17/Fading-a-24bit-transparent-PNG-in-IE7)

Unfortunately, this means that it’s impossible to have transparent PNGs fading in over a transparent background, since you have to apply a background color to the parent element in order for the transition to go smoothly, i.e. without the black pixels. `background: transparent` won’t work (since `transparent` isn’t really a color). :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm loading some png's dynamically into the DOM... this worked for me: http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Answer (score 1):

I've got the ultimate solution for this damn IE-PNG-BlackBorderProblem when using fading or other jQuery effects. It is working in every IE > 6 even in IE8!:

1. Download jQuery's pngFix at: http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/
2. Modify this script by searching:
   `if (jQuery.browser.msie && (ie55 || ie6)) {`
   and replace it with: 
   `if (jQuery.browser.msie) {`
3. create a blank.gif (1x1 transparent gif)
4. put a:
   `.pngFix( {blankgif: '< relative location to the blank.gif >'} );`
   at the end of the line where you perform jQuery effects eg.
   `$('#LOGO').animate( {'top': '40%', 'opacity': '1.0'}, 2500 ).pngFix( {blankgif: './library/img/blank.gif'} );`
5. make sure that all pictures have been loaded before you use jQuery effects within your document ready function by using the .load event on the window DOM-Element:

   `$(document).ready( function() {`
       `$(window).load( function() {`
           `$('#LOGO').animate( {'top': '40%', 'opacity': '1.0'}, 2500).pngFix( {blankgif: './library/img/blank.gif'} );`
       `});`
   `});`
6. Load page in IE8 and feel happy ;-)
7. You can see it in action on http://www.claudworks.net

No ugly dark borders anymore around some animated PNGs in IE.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Drupal Views Slideshow using the Fade transition on transparent PNGs.

I stumbled across the following quasi-solution totally by chance. I don't know why it works, but the drawback is it essentially removes the cross-fade envelope in IE (it doesn't appear to visibly affect FF or Safari):

Views Slideshow will print something like the following as part of its output:

```
<div class="views-field-field-photo-fid">
   <span class="field-content"><img height="433" width="834" src="http://devel.acupuncture2.polishyourimage.com/sites/acupuncture2.polishyourimage.com/files/pain_splash.png?1292552784" alt="" class="imagefield imagefield-field_photo"></span>
</div>
```

I hid views-field-field-photo-fid:

```
.views-field-field-photo-fid { width: 0px; }
```

Not perfect but maybe good enough till I find a better solution. You can take a look at the development site: http://acupuncture2.polishyourimage.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Weezy's solution but doesn't play nice with IE7. The effects is even worse.

When assigning jQuery opacity-property to animate-function instead of Black-Border-Bug it generates a Black&White-Border-Bug :-P So I did the following for IE8;

In the head IE8 conditional comment with the HTC behavior on class .fixpng especially for htc.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
        <style type="text/css">

               .fixpng { 
                        /* this fixes transparency in IE8 ONLY! */
                        behavior: url(css/IE8pngfix.htc); 
                        }
        </style>
<![endif]-->
```

changed HTC-file to IE8pngfix.htc. Changed line 75 in the .htc to

> !/MSIE
>   (8)/.test(navigator.userAgent

It's actually double-filtered, first IE conditional and then in htc, but what the hell!

I found that because htc could interfere with jQuery. Example;

```
  [div id="tooltip" class="fixpng"]
```

Had to change $(div#tooltip).css({opacity: 0}) to display:none in CSS and set display: 'block' in hover-event.

So if anybody has found a working solution for IE7 I would be really happy. All the workarounds /hacks above don't work for me. About IE6 I don't care any second.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I took Darko Z suggestion about the div. In the end this is what I had to do to be able to get jQuery Cycler fadeing FX to work on IE with drupal 7. Instead of placing an  tag I used divs and applied the.png to the background of the image along with

So I changed this:

```
<div class="fademe">
  <a href="http://mysite/node/1">
    <img class="firstTAB-phase2" src="http://mysite/IMG/bio_640x330.png" height="330px" width="640px" />
 </a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="http://mysite/node/1">
  <div class="fademe" id="TAB1"></div>
</a>
```

then in the css I did:

```
.fademe{ width:640px; height:330px;}
#TAB1{ background: #999 url(http://mysite/IMG/bio_640x330.png) no-repeat;}
```

and it works for now =D.

Hope it helps,
Defigo

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix to this bug, simply add the following to the wrapping div and to the img and other elements (e.g. h1,h2,p)

```
#div, #div img {    
    background:none !important; 
    filter:none !important;
}
```

This will fix it

Comment: This does work if you don't miss out the !. Also background property is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me mad for a couple of days and I finally stumbled across Unit's PNG fix. http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php - works with Cycle and stopped me from switching to a JPEG solution!

It needs a bit of tinkering to target specific PNGs in the cycle div, but she works!

Answer (score 0):

Hoping to help somebody else who encounters this problem:

I had transparent .png backgrounds (tiled) on a few divs on my page and when I activated the jquery cycle plugin, those transparent areas became screwy. They lost some of their transparency.

My solution was to simply make the tiles much bigger, so there really is no tiling at all. There is a small trade off for file size, but it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrited the fadeIn and fadeOut methods. It seems I don't get the black color on PNG image. No parent div is needed. Still you use as jQuery.

http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/fade.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to sacrifice a bit of image quality, you can save the images as PNG-8 instead of PNG-24, then apply the fix mentioned by Prosini, i.e.

```
cleartype: true, cleartypeNoBg: true
```

and that should work. With PNG-24, I was still getting a bit of black border during the transitions.

Answer (score 0):

While not specifically limited to the cycle plugin, this may help others. I came across this stream in my attempt to find a solution to .animate() transparent/translucent png files.  I had the issue of a black border occurring in both IE7 and IE8.  The images appear fine until I attempted to use JQuery to animate the opacity...

```
$('#my-png-img').stop().animate({opacity:0.0},3000);
```

I went thru a number of the solutions and unfortunately, none of them were ideal.  While this stream is a bit dated, it may help someone else still searching to piece together a solution. I ended up using the Twin Helix solution (http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) with a bit of a tweak.  I'm not a huge fan of .htc files but that's beside the point.  I edited the iepngfix.htc file (~line 75) to trap for IE7 and IE8.  I changed...

```
!/MSIE (5\.5|6)/.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
```

to

```
!/MSIE (5\.5|6|7|8)/.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
```

From there I followed the general instructions (see demo) including adding this bit to my CSS

```
/* IE PNG Fix */
img, div, a, input { 
    behavior: url(/_css/iepngfix.htc) 

}
```

In addition and as others have mentioned,  I had to nest my image in a container...

```
<div id="img-container"><img src="/images/my_semi_trans_png24.png" /></div>
```

Then I applied .animate() effect to the containing div.  A bit constraining however, this was the only way I was able to get fading to work consistently.  In one case, I even found that the transparency issue affected animating the opacity on a transparent .gif file.  Oh and, whether I used .fadeIn()/.fadeOut rather than .animate() made no difference.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My images are applied via the css background property, so I can't "wrap" them in a div.

Comment: FWIW, .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() just call the .animate() function internally in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[**Weezy**'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem/2372548#2372548) worked for me!

I tweaked the .htc file further, and changed this line:

```
var bgPNG = bgSrc.match(/url[("']+(.*\.png[^\)"']*)[\)"']/i);
```

to:

```
var bgPNG = bgSrc.match(/url[("']+(.*\.fixme.png[^\)"']*)[\)"']/i);
```

By doing this, the .htc script will ignore all .png files **unless** they end with .fixme.png (for example "transparant.fixme.png").  I intended this to speed up the script a little and ensure that only problem .pngs are fixed (the ones you must have transparant).

I use other .pngs which are **not** transparant, and therefore don't need this script to run against them.

Answer (score 0):

The best fix is [unitpngfix](http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php).

Include it in your script and be sure to provide the path to your 1px by 1px transparent gif. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

This is all pretty hectic stuff you're being asked to do. All very coding codingsky.

Here's my suggestion. IE will not allow a png background above a colored background to live in peace, like so...

```
    <div style="background:url('something.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll; position:absolute; z-index:2;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:#fa0237; position:absolute; z-index:1;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Notice the first div is z-index 2(on top of 2nd div).

This can be simplified by putting your bgColor in the background css in the 1st Div and doing away with the second div. This solves the problem of the black areas. I had this problem myself.

The only way I can see you having a problem where you can't use this method is where you have the need to overlay two png background images over one another and fade simultaneously. Don't do that. You'll need to animate each one after one another.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a solid background color to your image:

```
    .container img {
         background-color: white;
    }
```

1. Define the **background-image** css property of your image to its **src** attribute:

```
    $('.container img').each(function() {
         $(this).css('background-image', $(this).attr('src'));
    });
```

Advantage: you don't need to change your markup

Disadvantage: sometimes applying a solid background color is not an acceptable solution. It normally is for me.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue simply add:

"filter" : ""

to your .css() or .animate() and it'll fix a number of IE related issues.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable solution is to not use pngs in fading style animations in `<IE9` browsers.
I tried nearly every "fix" and variation of a fix available that I could find for this issue and had no success. The solution I used was to export pngs that were going to have fading-style animations applied to them (ie, fadeIn/fadeOut) to gifs and do a conditional replacement for `<IE9`. Although the gifs don't look as good as pngs in a modern browser, they look a hell of a lot better than the way IE8 and earlier render pngs, and this method works reliably. You still get to display nice pngs for capable browsers and when the fix is applied nothing else gets broken; most of the png hacks are known to break other css properties. Your code might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
      if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9)
      {
          $(".myClass, .myOtherClass").each(function (val)
          {
              var backgroundValue = val.css("background-image");
              backgroundValue.replace('.png', '.gif');
              $(this).css("background-image", backgroundValue);
              //you could just as easily do this with 'img' tags
          });
      }
}
```