# Problem with setting opacity by jQuery in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, opacity

I have this code:

```
<ul id='menu'>
  <li class="no1"> </li>
  <li class="no2"> </li>
  <li class="no3"> </li>
</ul>
```

Classes no1 - no3 just set background images for "li" tags. I use following code to set opacity of all **li** elements to 0.15 :

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function () {
      $('#menu > li').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.15'},"slow");
}
```

Everything is OK in Opera,Chrome,Safari and Firefox, but it doesnt work in IE7 and IE8
(and even maybe IE9)

I discovered I have to use **style.filter** property in IE but don't know how to exactly implement it in the code above. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The `opacity` css type does not exist in those versions of IE,

so do: `'filter': 'alpha(opacity=15)'`  for IE

[Read up on opacity here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)

Comment: well opacity is sketchy in IE

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#menu > li').stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.15);
```

Comment: check the answer from Eric on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375646/jquery-animate-opacity-doesnt-work-properly-on-ie

Answer (score 0):

css is filter:alpha(opacity=15); 
Not sure how the jquery syntax for assigning it will go though
I guess:

```
 $('#menu > li').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.15'; 'filter':'alpha(opacity=15)'},"slow");
```

Not entirely sure though.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work for image in background of LI tag. Any suggestion ?

Comment: try using comma then: $('#menu > li').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.15', 'filter':'alpha(opacity=15)'},"slow");

Comment: Or try this:  'filter':"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=15)"    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx