# animate() & fadeTo() both synchronous

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the following two methods. `$(this).fadeTo(200, .8).animate({bottom: 130}, 200);` Both are synchronous, therefore first it fades to, then it animates.

Is it possible to use `fadeTo` with `animate`?

(CSS option 'opacity' is not cross-browser compatible and therefore not an option)

Comment: In fact opacity is crossbrowser, how do you think jQuery does it ? You just need to fiddle with IE's filter properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).animate({
  bottom: 130,
  opacity: 0.8
}, 200);
```

jQuery will set things up to make opacity working on IE. See [Animate opacity doesn't work properly on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375646/jquery-animate-opacity-doesnt-work-properly-on-ie/1990728#1990728)