# Weird black spots on custom Google Map with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I'm getting some weird black spots with a [custom map page](http://www.spectraperu.com/localizador_poi.html) (via the Google Maps API v2.x) I have created. (Click SERVICIOS and then the icon farthest south to generate image shown below.) The issue seems to only appear when using Internet Explorer. I'm wondering if this is a common problem and if there is a common fix?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

In this picture the browser is IE 8.0.6001.18702

Its hard for me to get specific details about the computer because my client took this screenshot, I have been unable to reproduce these black spots.

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Comment: maybe they're blotting out Area 51... haha

Comment: It didn't happen for me in IE6 (work computer). It looks like it could be a problem with the transparency for the shadow PNG under the dialog.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring (You're about 6000km off. That's near Lima, Peru.)

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and Chrome. Fluke, maybe?

Comment: @Michael Todd, that's just what they want you to believe ;-)

Comment: In case nobody has noticed it: Those are missing parts from the drop shadow of the dialog box.

Comment: Just curious, is the client machine running short on system memory or has problems with page file?

Comment: Try deleting temporary files from IE cache!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This black (png?) bug might be related to this issue:

[IE 8 Black bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204457/how-to-solve-hack-fading-semi-transparent-png-bug-in-ie8)

What version of IE are you running? (Note that only some part of the drop shadow seems to be affected.)

Comment: Is it sad that I can tell he's running IE 8 just by looking at the screenshot?

Comment: +1 for diagnosis. Unfortunately, as you know, there is not a remedy.

Answer (score 3):

This is completely related to the zooming feature in IE8.  Ask your client to set his zoom level back to 100% and the black spots magically disappear.  This is probably why not everyone can reproduce this problem, because it's a local browser setting.  But even now (months later), when I follow your link -- or if I simply go to maps.google.com, do a search, and get the Marker/InfoWindow -- if I have the zoom level set to > 100%, I see those black shadow pieces where Google's javascript is trying to piece together the drop-shadow.  So QED: Microsoft STILL has a bug in their scaling algorithm for transparent PNGs in IE8.

[Weird black spots on custom Google Map with IE http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/751/googleblackholes.jpg](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/751/googleblackholes.jpg)

Comment: +1 It looks like you're right. Thanks for sharing this! ... I've added a screenshot as evidence.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  I was struggling with this, even with the Google Maps API, so when I figured it out, I just had to share.  Plus I have a 30" monitor, not that I'm trying to brag, but the dot pitch is so fine that I HAVE to use zooming & such!  So this is an issue that more people will see as time marches on, unless MS fixes it!

Answer (score 2):

I failed to reproduce this error (IE6,7,8,FF,Chrome), but I can offer you to try [GMaps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/wiki/Libraries). It allows to create custom info windows using css ([live example](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/12/extinfowindow-10-ajax-powered-css.html) that use [ExtInfoWindow](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extinfowindow/) library extension). This library adds you an opportunity to create info windows without transparency which I think is a current problem.

I've tryed to look what google map API doing with info window at IE8 and found that it add CSS filter:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale,src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/ru_ALL/mapfiles/transparent.png");
```

Wich reproduce shadow under the info window based on transparent png image, maybe at your client computer this opportunity (filter) disabled, so I think the best solution is to use library i suggested.

Also you can try [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) library that has IE-PNG fix transparent functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had this blackspot too. It is generated by the `<li>`.

Remove the `<li>` and `</li>` around the affected area and it will disappear.