# jQuery applying css opacity

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, opacity

I have tried to get the opacity to work in IE, I am testing in IE8 at the moment, Chrome etc works fine but IE8 is terrible.

My code has been:

```
$('#mydiv').animate({'opacity': '0.5'});
```

and

```
$('#mydiv').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

The opacity is applied to the images held within this div but none of the text, it's very infuriating :( can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found `fadeTo()` a reliable cross browser way to animate opacity. http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)"; /* IE 8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* older IEs */
```

hope this is helpful for you

Answer (score 4):

> $('#mydiv').fadeTo(0.5);

or

> $('#mydiv').fadeTo(500,0.5);

or

> $('#mydiv').fadeTo("slow",0.5);

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: Your first suggestion wont work since speed is the first argument, but this seems to be the most correct solution here.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does'nt apply opacity to elements withoute a layout. See this answer [Opacity CSS not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery handles setting the opacity in an IE ≥ 6 compatible way for you, both when using the [`css("opacity", value)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) and [`fade*()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) methods. But be sure to use the [**jQuery 1.x**](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-1-x) library which is compatible with IE 6, 7 and 8 as opposed to **jQuery 2.x** which is not (both are IE ≥ 9 compatible).

Here are the examples of using `css("opacity", value)` and `fadeTo(duration, opacity)`:

- **jQuery 1.x**: http://jsbin.com/xabexa/2/edit?html,js,output
- **jQuery 2.x**: http://jsbin.com/xabexa/3/edit?html,js,output

However, there are issues in IE ≤ 8 related to opacity of semi-transparent PNGs:
[How to solve/hack fading semi-transparent PNG bug in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1204457/686534)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

instead of

```
opacity:0.5;
```