# Fade in PNG fix for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, png, cycle

I am using the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to fade in an animation. This works fine on everything except for PNG files having half transparent pixels in them in IE8. The half transparent pixels are black during the fade.

Things i tried:

- [Unit PNG](http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php) : Solved it, but messed the CSS up so bad that it even makes it worse.
- [jquery.pngFix.js](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/) : Doesn't do anything.
- [Malsup's cycle tips](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-plugin-and-png-transparency-in-ie8-and-ie7): cleartype:false (no result) and cleartypeNoBg: true (Works, except for the fading itself).
- Adding BG-color: Works, but i'd like to background to be transparent. It doesn't work to add a transparent BG image.
- Trying [X-UA-Compatible mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) : Doesn't do anything.

Any guesses?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HaEym/

Answer (score 2):

It's not glamorous, but you can replace png's with gifs using IE specific css hacks. Once I had to show the PNG (because the gif was LQ, so after the animation I replaced the gif with the png.

For specific examples see another [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204457/how-to-solve-hack-fading-semi-transparent-png-bug-in-ie8)

Comment: But a gif replacement doesn't show half transparent pixels and that's what i need in this case. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Fully transparent pixels can do the trick for short animations. At some point we have to question fully supporting these older browsers. 
fwiw you could use Adobe Flash for the animation. Png is fully supported in flash.

Comment: I appreciate your support, but I am guessing it's simply not possible.. If i however find a solution i'll let you know. For now i'll just remove the fades in Iexplorer.