# Preventing animation based on boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, animation, opacity

As many of you will be aware, animating PNG's with alpha transparency in `<IE8` does not work very well. Therefore I would simply like to disable animating opacity in `<IE8`.

The only way I can see doing something like this is by doing this:

**HTML**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var browserUnsupported = true;
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Test if the browser is supported
if(browserUnsupported){
    // Hide the element
    $('#test').hide();
}else{
    // Fade out the element and then hide it
    $('#test').animate({
        opacity:0   
    },200,function(){
        $(this).hide();
    })
}

// Once the animation has completed, continue
setTimeout(function(){
    // This will execute once the animation has completed
    // We cannot use the callback in case the browser is unsupported
    // and the animate function has not been used
},200);
```

But this is a pretty long winded fix, especially if you consider that every time I would like to animate something, I have to do this.

**Can anybody come up with any better alternatives?**

Can you turn of animating opacity in Internet Explorer 8 and below? If there is a hack, please consider that I do not store my jQuery locally, I load it from the Google CDN. I will not be willing to alter the jQuery source, even if this is the only option.

**UPDATE**

I am not looking for a better method of detecting the browser version. The above code was just for illustrative purposes. What I would like to know is whether there is a way I can control the opacity animating by jQuery? Or, is there a better way to animate if condition, don't animate if not?

**UPDATE**

Something like this (not tested):

```
function myAnimate(styles,duration,easing,callback){
    // Get the selected element
    var element = this.elements;
    if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version<8){
        delete options.opacity;
    }
    // Call the animation method
    element.animate(options,duration,easing,callback);
}
```

Comment: This question has already been answered and apparently IE does support animating alpha transparency in PNG's. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4126528/861940

Comment: @Bruno Once again, please read the question in detail. This is not the correct fix. What about CSS background images? I have already determined that the background images cannot be animated in IE properly, with or without fixes. I simply want to disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example by using `$.browser` and `$.browser.version()` from jQuery

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8) {
 //fallback
} else {
 //real code
}
```

**Edit**

You could write your own execution function that extends jQuery to run functions based on conditions. If you had you condition being not internet explorer, then you could probably make sure that this kind of functions will not be called if you are in IE. The execute function could look like this (not tested it though)

```
$.fn.execute = function(a) {
    return this[a].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

condition = $.browser.msie;
$('div').execute(condition ? 'true' : 'false', function() {...});
```

Comment: Detecting whether the browser supports opacity is not the issue here! I am trying to come up with a good method of preventing the browser from animating if I know that the browser is unsupported

Comment: Please see my update. At the moment this answer is not relevant to my actual question, regardless of whether the info is helpful. If you are able to update it with an answer to the question I will remove the downvote and accept the answer

Comment: Still not sure If I'm getting your question correctly, but I've edited my answer.

Comment: Have removed downvote :-), it is similar to what I am looking for, but I think I have done it anyway. Will post up in a min

Comment: Is the `browser` object in jQuery fully supported and reliable or is it a recent addin?

Comment: The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3, and its functionality may be moved to a team-supported plugin in a future release of jQuery.

Comment: Exactly, so cannot be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

`$().fadeOut` does exactly what you want - animates the opacity and then hides:

```
if(ie){
  $("#test").hide()
}else{
  $("#test").fadeOut(200)
}
```

If you like terse code, you could do

```
$("#test").fadeOut(supported && 200)
```

Alternatively, you could [disable *all* animations globally](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/)

```
if(ie) $.fx.off = true;
```

or wrap your logic in a function that you can even add to jQuery:

```
$.fn.fadeIfSupported = function(){
  if(unsupported){
    this.hide()
  }else{
    this.fadeOut.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}
...
$("#test").fadeIfSupported(200);
```

Comment: I am not just animating opacity, this was just as an example. Otherwise the fix would be pretty simple as you have shown. FadeOut is not suitable. But your suggestion has given me an idea to just rewrite the animate method. That is probably what I will do :-)

Comment: @BenCarey you can still extend jQuery with your implementation so you only write it once

Comment: I will post up what I mean, I don't mean a complete rewrite of the animate method.