# Fading transparent image in IE7-8

Tags: internet-explorer, png, cycle, transparent, fade

I have been checking a lot of topics on this situation and still haven't found a solution to this problem. Is it even possible?

I have a website (http://dev.ultimate-web.dk) which uses the cycle plug-in (http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) to fade the top cases. As you see on the first image when the fading occurs, it gets a black border to fill out the semi-transparent pixels in IE7-8.

Why is that, and how can I fix - if I even can fix? It works it all other major browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has frustrated many a developer from time to time.  Unfortunately, the going solution seems to be to put the element in a container that has an opaque background and fade that container.

See [jquery cycle IE7 transparent png problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem) a few good answers.  I found a great page on this on the internet about 3 months ago but I'm struggling to find it now.  I'll keep looking though.

From [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=366899):

> The behavior you are seeing is a
>   design limitation of Opacity
>   Transition filter. This is not an
>   equivalent of the true CSS3 opacity
>   style. We aren't really using the
>   Technical Beta to collect feature
>   requests. However, we will consider
>   this feature request for a future
>   release.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The IE Team

Comment: Odd thing is I am fading the parent container (div.case) which has a background: transparent ! important; style. Hmm...

Comment: @meep - transparent won't work as the background colour of the parent container - it needs to be fully opaque.