# Jquery Slider PNG black borders IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, png

Greetings,

I'm having a lot of trouble with the IE8 buy of getting black borders when using a JQUERY slider, with PNG transparent images.

Using a slightly modified version of the Nivio slider.

I have searched high and low for fixes and blocks of code but so far none have worked.

What happens is that as soon as the img cycles it gets the black border and looks like shit (only in IE8).

Does anyone know a working fix for this?
Or do we just have to ban IE from all computers?

Comment: IE8 buy? I don't think I understand..?

Comment: Don't do fades with png's in IE8-

Answer (score 1):

Solutions here: [jquery cycle IE7 transparent png problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem)

Answer (score 0):

As I can recall this generally happens in IE7+ when a PNG with alpha channels is faded in or out, which uses opacity.

As for a fix, I was unable to find one, but there is the cause I believe.