# Bad pixel background image in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background-image

I had a small problem on **internet explorer 8 and 9** that image results are not as expected. Pixel quality is very poor, but in other browsers like chrome, opera, and firefox looks very good.

this is my results :

[image]

the images rendered by IE looks fractions on a circle, and this is my CSS code :

```
.social-profiles ul li.facebook a {
    background: url(img/flat-social-icons/32px/Facebook-32.png);
    text-indent: -9999;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */ }
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972818/ie-shows-black-border-around-png-when-faded-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit background image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with using the MSIE alpha filters with PNGs that possess alpha transparency themselves.

Your options are to:

- bake the transparency into the image itself with an alpha channel
- give the icons an opaque background that blends into the context
- give the icons a transparent background gradient by using the MSIE gradient filter

I would choose the third for flexibility, but the first is probably the fastest.