# how to show images with it's original smoothness in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i just disappoint with IE. how ever for image quality and better image view. Is there some thing css tricks for especially with IE that can show better Image appearance.

here is Image appearance of my screen in chrome :

[image]

here is Image appearance of my screen in IE :

[image]

i just want to know is that IE problem or there is my image problem or there is any way to fix this issue with css tricks.

please help me...

Comment: In which IE version you are checking this? also it seems that icons are png images so you might need to use option mate in photoshop save for web window

Comment: IE 8 . Is there alternative way to make convert this image png to gif image converter.

Comment: http://www.8bitalpha.com/ this online tool may help it converts PNG24 to PNG8 which may resolve your issue

Comment: this tool take long time

Comment: Photoshop is popular one in this case you just need to choose png8 option in save for web window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is known IE issue you may try with

```
img.imageclassname {
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */   
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */ 
}
```

possible duplicate of [IE shows black border around PNG when faded in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972818/ie-shows-black-border-around-png-when-faded-in)

try with this one!

Answer (score 0):

Just by what i have seen in the screenshots, I think the IE version is old or the browser is new but is rendering in an older standard (IE7 standards mode). Using F12 find out what mode IE is opening it. If it is opening it in an older mode, force browser to open in the latest mode by using the meta tag..

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

hopefully this helps.

Comment: the reason i am thinking older browser standards mode is because older standards like IE7 mode, does not render box-radius...which i see happening in the chrome screenshot.