# Javascript slideshow/carousel/slider for general HTML and good IE support

Tags: javascript, slider, slideshow, carousel

I have recently used a JQuery plugin called **cycle** to create slides of general HTML content in my homepage ([www.inspirastudios.com](http://www.inspirastudios.com)). Everything looked OK in Firefox and Chrome but while browsing the site with a client I got the ugly surprise of Internet Explorer 7 rendering my slides within an ugly gray background. Do you know:

1. how to solve this, **or**
2. any decent javascript slideshow/carousel/slider library that supports general HTML (not only images), previous and next slide activation buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nivo slider has all the features that you are looking for.  http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

You might be facing the following problem: [jquery cycle IE7 transparent png problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem)

Comment: From the Nivo website: _«Note that only images or images wrapped in links are allowed in the slider div»_

Comment: Sorry, that was my oversight.  jQuery Cycle appears to be your best bet.  Did you take a look at jquery cycle IE7 transparency png problem link?  Also, you could look at other sliders: http://goo.gl/Y2sIo (Google Search)

Comment: I found the fix for JQuery Cycle plugin in the thread you suggested. I followed the instructions in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem#1240097) and it worked. Thanks a lot!