# Javascript: changing opacity using .style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + ... + ')' makes the png background replace alpha channel with black in IE7

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a website without jquery but I ran into this problem. (Javascript: changing opacity using `.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + ... + ')'` makes the png background replace alpha channel with black).

This is my first post, so I'm sorry if I've asked in the wrong place.

Please tell me if you require a link for such an example. (I don't have it yet)

Thank you.

**This problem occurs as far as I know in IE7**

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery cycle IE7 transparent png problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156985/jquery-cycle-ie7-transparent-png-problem)

Comment: Have you tried other with browsers? IE7 is quite out of date...

Comment: Known IE bug (I think IE9 finally fixed it) - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714